# How to update my DNS record to point to Azure VM website?

Tags: azure, dns, iis-6, windows-server-2012-r2

I have recently setup a VM in Azure and migrated my website from existing server to Azure. Previously my website pointing to the static IP of my server in A record.

May I know how should I update my DNS record so that it is pointing to my Azure now? From my Azure portal there are 3 different things,

DNS NAME: XXX.cloudapp.net

PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP (VIP) ADDRESS: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

INTERNAL IP ADDRESS: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

Which should I used? I tried using CNAME and point to XXX.cloudapp.net but it is not responding. Or is it that I need to point to the same address which I used to RDP: XXX.cloudapp.net:XXX which has port no. behind?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create an A record pointing to your public virtual IP address.  At least with AWS that's exactly what I do.  Azure should be the same.

Comment: Would the VIP change when the server is restarted or refreshed?

Comment: In Amazon Web Services, you can assign a permanent public IP to your server (called an Elastic IP).  Azure must have something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It is working now under CNAME, previously it was due to shared configuration problem. Took whole day to find out.

Comment: yes but that wont work for naked domains, like http://example.com you need a A record to a fixed IP!